# What do the triple dots (...) in a julia array do? Why do they change the type signature?

Tags: julia

Given the data types bellow, the following comprehension yields two `Array{Any,1}` of `Player`s:

```
[[team.players for team in [big_team_1, big_team_2]]]
```

This next comprehension, however, yields the desired result of an `Array{Player,1}` of 12 elements:

```
[[team.players for team in [big_team_1, big_team_2]]...]
```

What exactly is the `...` doing? Where is this documented?

---

Data:

```
type Player
  ranking::Int
end

type Team
  players::Array{Player}
end

team_1 = Team([Player(10_000), Player(11_000), Player(9_000), Player(8_500),
                   Player(20_000), Player(10_500)])

team_2 = Team([Player(i.ranking + 3000) for i in team_1.players])
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`args...` and `; kwargs...` is the *splat* operator, if you know Python, it's the same as `*args` and `**kwargs`:

You can find documentation here: [What does the splat `...` operator do?](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/faq/?highlight=splat#what-does-the-operator-do)

### When in method signature (collects arguments).

```rb
julia> function foo(pos_1, pos_2, opt_1 = :opt_1, args...;
                    opt_kw1 = :opt_kw1, opt_kw2 = :opt_kw2, kwargs...)
           [pos_1, pos_2, opt_1, args, opt_kw1, opt_kw2, (kwargs,);]
       end
foo (generic function with 2 methods)
```

This signature means:

- `pos_1` is the first required positional argument.
- `pos_2` is the second required positional argument.
- `opt_1` is an optional positional argument.
- `args...` are all the following positional arguments, collected in a tuple.

Notice how semi colon `;` separates positional arguments from keyword arguments (order is not important in key word arguments):

- `opt_kw1` is an optional keyword argument.
- `opt_kw2` is an optional keyword argument.
- `kwargs...` are all the following keyword arguments collected in an array of tuple (key, value) pairs.

---

```rb
julia> methods(foo)
# 2 methods for generic function "foo":
foo(pos_1, pos_2) at none:3
foo(pos_1, pos_2, opt_1, args...) at none:3
```

`foo` can be called like this:

Required arguments:

```rb
julia> foo(:pos_1, :pos_2)
7-element Array{Any,1}:
 :pos_1      # provided value
 :pos_2      # provided value
 :opt_1      # default value
 ()          # empty tuple
 :opt_kw1    # default value
 :opt_kw2    # default value
 (Any[],)    # there are no kwargs
```

Optional positional and keyword arguments:

```rb
julia> foo(:pos_1, :pos_2, :OPT_1, :a, :b, :c,
           opt_kw2 = :OPT_KW2, kwarg1 = true, opt_kw1 = :OPT_KW1, kwarg2 = false)
7-element Array{Any,1}:
 :pos_1
 :pos_2
 :OPT_1
 (:a,:b,:c)
 :OPT_KW1
 :OPT_KW2
 (Any[(:kwarg1,true),(:kwarg2,false)],)
```

Notice how the order in key word arguments is not relevant, also the semicolon `;` is not needed when calling the function.

---

### When in function call (spreads arguments).

Using collections for the positional arguments and assosiative collections with symbol keys for the keyword arguments:

```rb
julia> x, y, z = 1, 2, 3;

julia> sum(x, y, z)
ERROR: MethodError: `sum` has no method matching sum(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  sum(::Union{Base.Func{1},Function}, ::AbstractArray{T,N}, ::Any)
  sum(::Union{Base.Func{1},DataType,Function}, ::Any)
  sum(::BitArray{N}, ::Any)
  ...

julia> sum
sum (generic function with 12 methods)

julia> Base.sum(args...) = sum(args)
sum (generic function with 13 methods)

julia> sum(x, y, z)
6

julia> foo(x, y, z) = sum(x, y, z)
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(x, y, z)
6

julia> foo([x, y, z])
ERROR: MethodError: `foo` has no method matching foo(::Array{Int64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  foo(::Any, ::Any, ::Any)

julia> foo([x, y, z]...)
6
```

---

```rb
julia> foo(; x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) = sum(x, y, z)
foo (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> foo()
0

julia> foo(z = 3, x = 1, y = 2)
6

julia> foo(; Dict(:z => 3, :y => 2, :x => 1))
ERROR: TypeError: anonymous: in typeassert, expected Symbol, got Pair{Symbol,Int64}
 in anonymous at no file

julia> foo(; Dict(:z => 3, :y => 2, :x => 1)...)
6
```